# Dramatic improvement in radar energy use?

Tags: radar

I was reading over [a history of RAF Saxa Vord](http://ahistoryofrafsaxavord.blogspot.com) - everyone needs a hobby. This station started in the 1950s with an S-band Type 80 which had either 1 or 2 MW focussed into a 0.3 degree beam. That was replaced years later with an L-band Maretllo of about 132 kW, and recently by an L-band FPS-11 with a whopping 25 kW. Beamwidth has *increased* to 3 degrees, and gain is generally lower (not surprising given the smaller antennas).

So we appear to be looking at *four orders of magnitude* less energy (per pulse) being returned from the target. And rotation rate is about the same, so it's not like its a better dwell time to make up for this. Yet the system has (apparently) the same basic range performance.

So, why? I imagine this must be due primarily to improvements in the receiver electronics, but beyond that I can't really say I know much about military receiver tech. Can anyone comment?

Comment: Maybe it accumulates "image" data over many successive spins?

Comment: @Andyaka it's usually the *differences* between successive spins you need to worry about...

Comment: @BrianDrummond but those differences are a small part of the bigger constant picture and maybe when something moving is detected it uses much higher power and slows the rotation speed down (or even tries to track it) and gets improvements that way. Long term average might still be 25 kW and average rotation rate about the same (long term) BUT, because I speculate with gay abandon, I voted to close the question some time ago!

Answer (score 2):

Many, many years ago I was an RAF radar tech, and we studied this - although I have forgotten much of it. I'll try to answer as best as I can remember.

Huge, huge improvements in receiver technology is correct. The very early systems were all valve don't forget, and pretty simple (by today's standards). Even when I studied this, systems ( this was 1980's) used all kinds of techniques to help pick out the pulse from the noise, and also to avoid blocking. Things have obviously come a long way since - I can't imagine what they must be up to now.

If we are talking long-range air-defence detection, there is a constant technology war going on - for aircraft to detect incoming pulses and either evade them (for instance by making the aircraft hard to pick out, by design of the shape and/or use of special materials) or block/confuse them (by re-transmitting misleading pulses, blocking, and so on).

For the radar people it is the other way around : they want to transmit lower power pulses because it is harder for the plane to detect them and interfere. I imagine that by now they use techniques that go far beyond the standard convolution and so on, to help detect the echo in the noise. Even on simple systems, the ratio of transmitted to received power was enormous; by now it is probably staggering.

Comment: I'm wondering if much of this is due to the use of GaAs circuits in the receivers? I see many mentions of systems using this, would they have lower natural noise and thus boost the S/N?

Comment: from memory, GaAs was just coming in when I had my introduction to this field - and yes, I recall that it was seen as quite an important technology.